# string length of tricky string in php

Tags: php, string

I have two strings like this

```
$text = 'Abcdef';
$text[7] = 'Ghijk';
```

When I take the length of `$text` by

```
echo strlen($text);
```

The answer is `8`. Can Any body describe how is it?

Comment: Try `echo $text` after `$text[7] = 'Ghijk';` this line. what it returns?

Comment: I have echoed after this line. the result is of two lines. Before `$text[7]` it is 6 but after `$text[7]` it is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a simpler example to see what happens:

```
$text = 'a';
$text[2] = 'boo'; // now $text is "a b"
```

When PHP sees that we are accessing index `2` of the string whose length is 1 (with only valid index being 0), it ***extends*** the string by adding two spaces, so it makes the string `'a '`.

Next the index operator `[]` deals with characters in the string. So your second statement replaces the 3rd character with a `b`, giving you `a b`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you can access to characters in string like to items in array. So `$text[7] = 'Ghijk'` add to `$text` chracter 'G' on 8th position (from zero to seven)

```
$text = 'Abcdef';
$text[7] = 'Ghijk';

var_dump($text); //outputs string(8) "Abcdef G"
```

Comment: This is strange na? Even if it is considering the $text as array even then it should add the whole sting not only G

Answer (score 1):

`$text[7] = 'Ghijk';` adds 'G' at index position 7. As such, when you call `echo strlen($text);`, the result will be 8 because PHP uses 0-index addressing for strings.

To make more sense of this, consider the following code sample:

```
$text = 'Abcdef';
echo($text . ' ' . strlen($text) . '<br />');
$text[7] = 'Ghijk';
echo($text . ' ' . strlen($text) . '<br />');
echo($text[7]);
```

This produces

```
Abcdef 6
Abcdef G 8
G
```

The point is the line `$text[7] = 'Ghijk';` is only adding 'G'.

Comment: This is strange na? Even if it is considering the $text as array even then it should add the whole sting not only G

Comment: It's a char array, not a string array - when you add the 'G', the array length (strlen) is 8.

Comment: PHP, IMO is too lax here. `$text[7] = 'Ghijk';` should fail, rather than silently adding only 'G' and ignoring the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are internally implemented as char arrays. When you do something like `$text[7] = 'Ghijk';` it applies the first character(as its a char array) in new string i.e. 'G' to 7th place in original string, 6th place in string is empty. Thus making it 8 char long.

chars are 0=>'A'  6=>' '  7=>'G'

Comment: and it is creating the 7th character of white space as its own? If we will give `$text[8]='Ghijkl' then the answer should be `9`?